# Max and min of a three variable function over a set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

I need help for the following exercise, because I am not sure of myself.
Consider the function

$$f(x, y, z) = -(xy + zy)^2 + x - z$$

and the set $$A = \{ (x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3; xy + zy + x - z = 0 \}$$

- Does $g(t) = f(e^t, 1, e^t)$ have absolute max/min as $t$ changes in $\mathbb{R}$ ?
- Does $f(x, y, z)$ have absolute max/min over $A$? If yes, find it/them.

**My Attempts**

So, for what concerns the first request, I just calculated

$$g(t) = -4e^{2t}$$
And this is a monotone decreasing function over $\mathbb{R}$ hence it has no max/min (absolute or relative).

For what concerns the second request, I'm a bit perplexed.

First of all, I don't know how to show if $A$ is bounded and or closed (not asked, but I always want to do this part). So I have no clue if I could use Weierstrass theorem, for not knowing if $A$ is compact cannot make me to proceed.

But alas, in spite of that, I went on.

I wrote the set $A$ in function of $z$ as $z = \frac{x(1+y)}{1-y}$ and I thence wrote $f$ restricted to that

$$f\bigg|_z = -\frac{2xy}{1-y}\left(1 + \frac{2xy}{1-y}\right)$$

At this point I calculated the gradient (tedious):

$$\nabla f = \left(-\frac{4 x y^2}{(1-y)^2}-\frac{2 y \left(\frac{2 x y}{1-y}+1\right)}{1-y},-\frac{2 x \left(\frac{2 x y}{1-y}+1\right)}{1-y}-\frac{2 x y \left(\frac{2 x y}{1-y}+1\right)}{(1-y)^2}-\frac{2 x y \left(\frac{2 x y}{(1-y)^2}+\frac{2 x}{1-y}\right)}{1-y}\right)$$

Now, I found only two solutions: $x = y = 0$ and $y = \frac{1}{1-4x}$ (with $x \neq 0$).

At this point I don't know if I should proceed with the Hessian study, or not.
Maybe there is a more conveniente way to attack this problem. I'm just puzzled about the set $A$, I cannot figure it out in terms of what it does represent.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try the substitutions $u=xy+zy$ and $v=z-x$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField That is smooth! In this way the set $A$ is just a plane, right? Hence it's a closed set but not bounded. Hence no Weierstrass

Comment: Can you tell me if I'm correct? Restricting $u = -v$ I get
$$f(v) = -v^2+v$$
The critical point is $v = 1/2$ (hence $u = -1/2$).
$$f(-1/2, 1/2) = 1/4$$

But how to go back to $x, y, z$?

Comment: The substitution is its own function $g(x,y,z): \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ so you'll need to use the chain rule.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Sorry I expressed myself bad. I meant: after having found the values of $u$ and $v$ I cannot find the values of $x, y, z$. I have two equations and three unknown. I mean there are infinite many values for which $xy + zy = -1/2$ and $z-x = 1/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the exercise is correct - $g(t)$ has no minimum nor maximum over $\mathbb{R}$.

For the second part:

1. it can be shown that $A$ is closed and unbounded

   $h(x,y,z) = xy+zy+x−z $ is a continuous function and as ${0}$ is a closed set then $h^{-1}(0)=A$ is a closed set.

   Take $(x,y,z)\in A$ such that $y=1$, $x=0$ and $z\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $f(x,y,z) = -z(z+1)$ diverges to $-\infty$ as $z\rightarrow\infty$. So $f$ is not bounded in $A$.
2. As shown in the example before, $f$ has no minimum in $A$ as we can find points of $A$ arbitrarily small. But it has a maximum

   if $(x,y,z)\in A$ then $(x+z)y=-(x-z)$ and so for every point in $A$, the function $f$ becomes

$$f(x,y,z)=-(x-z)^2+(x-z)$$

Note that then $f(x,y,z)=-a^2+a=-a(a-1)$ with $a=x-z\in\mathbb{R}$.
And this function has a maximum at $a=x-z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Please let me know if something is not clear!

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I managed (thanks to the hints in the comments) to achieve that there was a critical point (but not classified, so now I know it's a maximum). I was wondering of this: is the solution just that one? If I understand well, there are then infinitely many points that satisfy $x-z = 1/2$, hence are there infinite many points of max?

Comment: Yes, exactly! There are infinitely many solutions such that $f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{4}$ and it always happen when $(x+z)y=-(x-z)$ and $x-z=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ahhh, thank youuu!! 
If it's not too much of disturb, can I ask you some hint about another question of mine too? 
This one: (only if / when you have time and will) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4758564/convexity-and-concavity-of-a-function-with-parameter